# How to create a lua function that gets called for a vim (neovim) motion

Tags: lua, object-motions, vimscript-lua

Vim has the concept of actions, which can act on text objects via motions.
For example `diw` will delete (the action) the inner word (the motion).
I want to create a function that can be applied/executed with those motions. For example, if my function appends to certain register, I can append whatever I want by doing `myFunction + motion for what I want to add`.

Comment: Have you read [`:h operator`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#operator), [`:h 'operatorfunc'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27operatorfunc%27) and [`:h :map-operator`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-operator). I think there is all the information you need there. If not you should try to implement what you want to do and edit your question with actual issues you're encountering.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will read it and will try to update my question, but the main problem seems to be that it is vimscript specific and that you can only have one global function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Scripting language does not matter. The help for mappings is in `:h map.txt`. Specific topic is `:h :map-operator`.
2. There is `g@` normal operator and `opfunc` global string option.
3. In order to perform "custom action" we must

   1. Make sure `opfunc` is set to the name of appropriate VimScript callable object;
   2. Execute `g@` in normal mode (that triggers the transition into operator-pending mode);
   3. Make sure Vim is left hanging in operator-pending mode;
4. After operator-pending mode is done `g@` saves the selected range to the "brackets" bookmark and invokes `opfunc` value passing an extra string parameter.
5. The quick and dumb test is `set opfunc=v:lua.print` and then type `g@aw` (prints "char"), `g@as` (prints "line"), `g@^VG` (prints "block") and so on.
6. As we probably want more than one user-defined operator, we should pack all of that 1-2-3 into a new mapping.
7. Implement actual `opfunc` function to do something useful.

BTW. appending text to a register is a builtin. Like `"Ayiw` etc.

UPD. Some example implementation for 1-2-3:

By `:h :map-expression`

```
function! Gat(method) abort
    let &opfunc = a:method
    return "g@"
endfunction

nnoremap <expr><f12> Gat("v:lua.print")
```

By `:h :map-cmd`

```
nnoremap <f12> <cmd>set opfunc=v:lua.print<CR>g@
```

Comment: Seems that some logic to setup a global lua function and also restore the previous opfunc is required. Can you also probide an example of 6? A mapping that performs the correct sequence to call opfunc?

Comment: @Danielo515 You don't need to restore anything as long as you don't use `g@` directly. As for the mapping, either `:map-expression` or `:map-cmd` wil do. A basic example is under `:h :map-operator` mentioned above. If you want to explore somewhat advanced use case check [this plugin](https://github.com/matveyt/vim-opera).

Comment: Does you new answer require the lua function to be globally available?

Comment: @Danielo515 I don't quite understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: because you are just referencing a globally available lua function (print) I think your solution requires the function to use to be global

Comment: @Danielo515 I still don't understand what you're trying to suggest. What answer does NOT have a global? How could that be that something is globally callable while nothing is global at the same time? Do you mean that strange piece of code that you took from github? Do you understand that it has TWO globals instead of ONE? With one of them being constantly recreated, i.e. recompiled? Even if it has been deleted, it requires no other function with this name to be at global scope. The only good reason for this would be if the outer function were generic as in the plugin I linked before.

Comment: chill mate, I am not saying your solution has any problem or is better/worse, I'm just trying to understand it in order to be able to implement it for my own purposes. My question objective is to understanding that, if I want to use the function you suggested, I need to set my function as `_G.MyFn` or not, that's all. Yes, I do understand the piece of code I posted by the way.

Comment: @Danielo515 `_G` is doing absolutely nothing. In lua everything is global unless it has been declared as `local`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer from Matt has pointed out, it is required to modify the opfunc to point to a global callable object and then call the `g@` + motion keymap. This is even suggested by the vim docs, where they create a mapping where both the opfunc is set and then the `g@` motion is called on the same command.
This seems to be the closer you can get using lua [until they provide a better lua integration](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/14157)

```lua
function format_range_operator()
  local old_func = vim.go.operatorfunc -- backup previous reference
  -- set a globally callable object/function
  _G.op_func_formatting = function()
    -- the content covered by the motion is between the [ and ] marks, so get those
    local start = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, '[')
    local finish = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_mark(0, ']')
    vim.lsp.buf.range_formatting({}, start, finish)
    vim.go.operatorfunc = old_func -- restore previous opfunc
    _G.op_func_formatting = nil -- deletes itself from global namespace
  end
  vim.go.operatorfunc = 'v:lua.op_func_formatting'
  vim.api.nvim_feedkeys('g@', 'n', false)
end
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "gm", "<cmd>lua format_range_operator()<CR>", {noremap = true})
```

Picked from: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/wiki/User-contributed-tips#range-formatting-with-a-motion

Comment: Don't use `feedkeys`. This is too dirty and (almost) never needed. Also, creating two functions instead of one and then deleting one of them... This makes no sense.

Comment: Can you explain why it is dirty to use feedkeys? what is the alternative? The creation  of two functions is required so you call the normal function from a command and that function does all the environment setup before calling the required mappings. I will be happy to see a cleaner implementation if you know one

Comment: I had updated my answer already.